# Add column with same prefix only if it s already existing in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, dplyr

Here is my dataframe

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100455", "1100464", "1100464"),
                  CATEGORIE = c("10110", "10160", "10604", "11220", "10110", "10110","10140"),
                  RANK =  c("1", "1", "1", "1", "0" ,"1", "1"),
                  MD =  c("0", "0", "0", "3", "4", "0", "0" ),
                  PROD = c(2345.00,1114.58,501.40,0.00,0.00,2720.00,636.80),
                  VALUE = c(540.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  QANT = c(50.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,50.00,0.00,0.00),
                  VALUE3 = c(563.76,0.00,17.35,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
                  PROD3 = c(4100,2100,1740,265,0,3978,940)
)
```

What i want to achieve is to add columns to the same name columns if it end with number 3 and if it exists, like PROD and PROD3 for example, I can do it like this

```
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(PROD = if (exists('PROD3', where=.)) PROD + PROD3 else PROD)
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(VALUE = if (exists('VALUE3', where=.)) VALUE + VALUE3 else VALUE)
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(QANT = if (exists('QANT3', where=.)) QANT + QANT3 else QANT)
```

It works for each case, but I would to do it with a list (l_data < c("PROD", "VALUE", "QANT")) as a parameter and without repeating the same syntax for each variable ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

I made it like this, i guess there is multiple ways (apply for example)

```
l_data <- c("PROD", "VALUE", "QANT")

for(item in l_data) {
  var3 <- paste0(item, "3")
  if (var3 %in% colnames(df2)) {
    df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(!!item := get(item) + get(var3))
  }
}
```

Comment: So I was trying to do similar using `mutate_if`, using `%in%`. But for some reason `get(paste0(deparse(substitute(.x),'3')))` is not working. Do post if you can make it work with `mutate_if`.